# Exposing a subset of WSDL soap operations

Tags: java, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

I'd like to know if there is any service available to expose a subset of wsdl operations. I want to upload my wsdl to a service and then select operations of this wsdl to share with partners.

For example Partner 1 would have search and pay, and partner 2 would have only search operation. Also I would like to manipulate responses of my API filtering some attributes or be able to mock responses of certain operations, i.e search for partner 3 would return only 2 products without really calling my API.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

if i understand correctly you have web service with say 3 operations.
you want to expose 2 operations to one user and 1 operation to another user/consumer

what did you group these operations in first place? why don't you provide 2 different WSDLs and 2 different services if you want to restrict

one option is to use a ESB ,like mule etc to achieve it.

you can expose this serviceoperation 1 as one mule service and other as another one.

so the wsdl you give to your consumer will be abstracted of your original webservice operations etc.

with mule/ESB you can do mocking by just simple xslt transformation.

Comment: why not using an API manager? I don't want to expose more than one wsdl cheers